# SQL Server result side by side

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables and I want to join or put them side by side in sql server but I'm unable to do it

```
select download_date, count(download_date) as CDC 
from cdc 
group by Download_Date

select COUNT(download_date) as cdcVillage 
from Sec0_cdcvillage 
group by Download_Date

select COUNT(download_date) as Sec1_Participants 
from Sec1_Participants 
group by Download_Date
```

When I use join all the value become same; is there any other way?

[image]

I want a result like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, with CTE.  I assume download_date exists in all tables :

```
;with cdc as
    (select download_date, count(download_date) as CDC from cdc group by Download_Date),
cdcVillage as
    (select COUNT(download_date) as cdcVillage from Sec0_cdcvillage group by Download_Date),
Sec1_Participants as
    (select COUNT(download_date) as Sec1_Participants from Sec1_Participants group by Download_Date)
select cdc.download_date, cdc.cdc, cdcVillage.cdcVillage, Sec1_Participants.Sec1_Participants
from cdc
    inner join cdcVillage on cdc.download_date = cdcVillage.download_date
    inner join Sec1_Participants on cdc.download_date = Sec1_Participants.download_date
```

**EDIT**

Unsure why (mayby my alias cdc match table cdc), try this one :

```
;with tcdc as
    (select download_date, count(download_date) as CDC from cdc group by Download_Date),
tcdcVillage as
    (select download_date, COUNT(download_date) as cdcVillage from Sec0_cdcvillage group by Download_Date),
tSec1_Participants as
    (select download_date, COUNT(download_date) as Sec1_Participants from Sec1_Participants group by Download_Date)
select tcdc.download_date,
       tcdc.cdc,
       tcdcVillage.cdcVillage,
       tSec1_Participants.Sec1_Participants
from tcdc
    inner join tcdcVillage on tcdc.download_date = tcdcVillage.download_date
    inner join tSec1_Participants on tcdc.download_date = tSec1_Participants.download_date;
```

Comment: thanks for your fast replay but it says "Recursive common table expression 'cdc' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator"

Comment: Sorry for asking too many questions but this time it says "Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"